# How to create subdirectories inside /home/{user}/ for all existing users using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a local path for all existing users with subdirectory local `/home/{username}/.local` under this path  `/home/{username}` 
for every clusters within the system.

**For example**

```
/home/user1/.local
/home/user2/.local
        .
        .
        .
/home/usern/.local
```

And none of the clusters have the same number of users, some user may not subsist in the particular cluster.

Does it possible to do that?

From my perspective, I will

1. looping for gathering all the users under /home/ and append to list variable or file.
2. create user path with their variable.

What should I start with ? or any better ideas here ?

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to *find* all directories in /home and create the directories

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: /home
        file_type: directory
      register: result
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ item.path }}/.local"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

In addition to this, it is possible to read *passwd* and limit the loop to users of the system only

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - find:
        paths: /home
        file_type: directory
      register: result
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: "{{ item.path }}/.local"
      loop: "{{ result.files }}"
      when: item.path|basename in getent_passwd.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the find module to find all the directories present in `/home`, then based on that criteria, create a directory in it.

This is a dirty way to do it:

```
---
- hosts: some_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: hacky way to do create directories in /home/*/
      shell: "for dir in /home/* ; do mkdir $dir/.local ; done"
```